# Elastic Beanstalk: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars: No such file or directory`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sidekiq

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Rails app. I'm trying to setup Sidekiq too, using script below. However I keep getting error `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars: No such file or directory`. I SSH into the EC2 instance and the directory does exist. I'm not sure what did I do wrong here

[Gist I'm currently using](https://gist.github.com/bnhansn/357916e6a4ec86cd8a3f9295dc986622)

Errors I'm getting:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-03a6fa2e1b96474be] Command failed on instance. Return code: 10 Output: (TRUNCATED)...hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_sidekiq: line 3: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars: No such file or directory
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_sidekiq: line 7: cd: HOME not set
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_sidekiq failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Comment: What path exists /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars or /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars ?

Comment: @error2007s I missed that. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars is the one that exist. But I'm getting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars. But the script is finding the one in support, not containerfiles. Now I'm a bit confused, again

Comment: Try creating this path opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars and then try the installation